# how does `make single-target` command work in a makefile with `include directive`

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to figure out how `makefile` work with `make` and `make sometarget` command. As I know, the `makefile` will first read the whole makefile, then it will try to update the target specified in the command. Then if the `makefile` has `include directive`, it will read the `makefile`, then try to update the include file, if the include file is updated then reread the `makefile`. My understand works fine with `make` command, but has problem with `make single-target' command.

Maybe my understand of `makefile` is wrong, I need some advice.

I tested my toy makefile on Ubuntu 16.04, with GNU Make 4.1.

The Project tree is:

```sh
.
├── bar.mk
└── Makefile

0 directories, 2 files
```

the `bar.mk` is:

```sh
$(warning "Reading from file: bar.mk")
```

the `Makefile` is:

```sh
include bar.mk
include BUILD.mk
$(warning Finished include)

all: test
    touch $@

test:
    @echo "target is test"

$(warning new warning)

BUILD.mk: bar.mk
    touch $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf all BUILD.mk
```

when I use `make test` command, the result is:

```sh
bar.mk:1: "Reading from file: bar.mk"
Makefile:3: Finished include
Makefile:11: new warning
target is test
```

and the project tree is:

```sh
.
├── bar.mk
├── BUILD.mk
└── Makefile

0 directories, 3 files
```

It doesn't reread the `makefile`, and from the bash output, it doesn't execute the `touch BUILD.mk` command, how does `BUILD.mk` file be created?

Comment: In `BUILD.mk`, try replacing `touch $@` with something like `echo '$$(warning I am here)' >$@`

Comment: @tripleee Thank you. I tried your suggestion, the result is similar to the original. It looks like updating the `BUILD.mk` file without printing the file created command, then the file not need to be updated, so it won't reread the entire Makefile. I don't understand the principle.

Comment: I get more output in both cases. Demo: https://ideone.com/Jv8WJE

Answer (score 0):

> As I know, the `makefile` will first read the whole makefile, then it will try to update the target specified in the command. Then if the `makefile` has `include directive`, it will read the `makefile`, then try to update the include file, if the include file is updated then reread the `makefile`.

No, that's not quite right:

- `make` does not read the main makefile to its end before processing `include` directives.  Instead, when it encounters an `include` directive as it processes a makefile, it interrupts processing of that makefile to *immediately*, at that point, read and process the included file.  The order of the first two lines of your output shows this to be happening.
- After reading and processing the whole makefile and all `include`d files, recursively, GNU `make` does check whether any of the makefiles involved can and should be rebuilt.  (Note that other `make` implementations don't necessarily do this.) If so, then it performs all such rebuilding and then restarts from scratch.
- Only after all the makefiles settle into a steady state are the targets specified on the command line or the default target built.

> It doesn't reread the `makefile`, and from the bash output, it doesn't execute the `touch BUILD.mk` command, how does `BUILD.mk` file be created?

Those conclusions seem to be based entirely on the reported output, but you appear to be looking only at a tail of the output corresponding to the second pass through the makefile.  There is no reason to believe that `BUILD.mk` is created otherwise than by `make` executing the rule for doing so, which the full output in fact reflects for me.

That's only when you run `make` while `BUILD.mk` is absent, though.  If you then run it again, `BUILD.mk` will not be built again because it already exists and is newer than its prerequisite, and therefore there will be only one reading of the overall makefile.  Perhaps you've confused yourself by considering only the output from such a run.